# SQL trying to replace middle characters with *

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to replace SQL results with all the middle values with asterix, *. All results are words. I am using SSMS.
The words that are 4-5 letters, it should only show 1 letter in the beginning, one to the end.
6 letters and more, it it should only show 2 letter in the beginning, 2 letters in the end.
1-3 letters, no replacement.

For example:
(I am now using - instead of * so it does not make the text bold).

"Banana" 6 letters should become ba--na

"False" 5 letters should become F---e

"a" stays the same

"Selin is a vegetable and banana is a fruit" becomes "S---n is a ve-----le and ba--na is a f---t."

What I have done so far, is to make this for emails, after the @. But now I want it to happen with every word of the result.

What I've done:

````sql
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100) = 'sample@gmail.com'

SELECT STUFF(STUFF(@STring,
                   CHARINDEX('@',@String)+2,
                   (CHARINDEX('.',@String, CHARINDEX('@',@String))-CHARINDEX('@',@String)-3),
                   REPLICATE('*',CHARINDEX('.',@String, CHARINDEX('@',@String))-CHARINDEX('@',@String)))
               ,2
               ,CHARINDEX('@',@String)-3
               ,REPLICATE('*',CHARINDEX('@',@String)-3))```
````

With result s----e@g------l.com

- instead of -

And I tried the mask method

```sql
Select 
--select first character from Email and use replicate
SUBSTRING(Sxolia,1,1) + REPLICATE('*',5)+ 
--function to put asterisks
SUBSTRING(Sxolia,CHARINDEX('@',Sxolia),len(Sxolia)-CHARINDEX('@',Sxolia)+1) 
--at this statement i select this part  @gmail,com and to first part to become like this A*****@gmail.com
as Emailmask
From [mytable]
```

With result
B***** Bana is a fruit

And

```
declare @str nvarchar(max)
select @str = '123456'

select '****' + substring(@str, 5, len(@str) - 3)
```

Result: ****56

Not what I am looking for.

How should I look into this?

Comment: *" 6 letters and more, it it should only show 1 letter in the beginning, 1 letter in the end"* So why does `'Banana'` become `'Ba**na'`?

Comment: Editing, 6 letters is 2 first 2 in the end.

Comment: Honestly, I feel like you'd be better off looking into [Dynamic Data Masking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I *had* to deal with this in SQL Server I'd operate on each word as a row, however using *string_split* is not (currently) an option since it does not guarantee ordering.

The following uses json to split the string as an array and provides a `key` value for ordering, which allows the words to be aggregated in the correct order:

```
select t.Sentence, 
  String_Agg( masked, ' ') within group(order by seq) Masked
from t
cross apply (
  select seq, [value] word,
  case 
    when l<=3 then [value]
      when l<=5 then Stuff([value],2,l-2,Replicate('*',l-2))
    else
      Stuff([value],3,l-4,Replicate('*',l-4))
  end Masked 
  from (
    select j.[value], 1 + Convert(tinyint,j.[key]) Seq 
    from OpenJson(Concat('["',replace(t.Sentence,' ', '","'),'"]')) j
  )w
  cross apply (values(Len([value])))x(l)
)w
group by t.Sentence;
```

See [working demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=66aa2fcec9d972a49f01784ff14c9f14)

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how e-mail fits into all this because you're asking for word masks, so I'm going to assume you actually want this. Use divide and conquer to implement this, so first implement an expression that would do this for simplest cases (e.g. single words). Then if you need it for e-mails, just split the e-mails however you see fit and then apply the same expression.

The expression itself is rather simple:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (VALUES 
      ('banana'),
      ('selin'),
      ('vegetable')
     ) words(word)
 CROSS
 APPLY (SELECT CASE 
                 WHEN ln BETWEEN 4 AND 5
                 THEN LEFT(word, 1) + REPLICATE('*', ln-2) + RIGHT(word, 1)
         
                 WHEN ln >= 6
                 THEN LEFT(word, 2) + REPLICATE('*', ln-4) + RIGHT(word, 2)
         
                 ELSE word
               END as result
          FROM (VALUES (LEN(words.word))) x(ln)
    ) calc
```

This already provides the expected result. You could define a function out of this, if you have the permissions, and use it like so:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (VALUES 
      ('banana'),
      ('selin'),
      ('vegetable')
     ) words(word)
 CROSS
 APPLY fnMaskWord(word)
```

[Here's a working demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0e61f9633ffcab8d742a23cfe82e37b6), it includes the statement to create the function.

Comment: Ok, but what about full sentences? Like when the result is "banana is a fruit" to become ba--na is a f----t?

Comment: That's a different problem. Split the string by spaces, apply the function, reaggregate the string back in the same order. There's plenty of questions and answers on how to split and aggregate. Also, are you quite sure you want to do it in SQL? It's possible, but it won't be a simple query and it'd just be a few lines of code in any procedural language. Btw editing questions to account for edge cases that have not been there in the first place and making the answers invalid is in poor taste tbh.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help

```
declare @t table (word varchar(50))
insert into @t values ('banana'), ('selin'), ('vegetable')

select case when len(t.word) < 3 then t.word
            else left(t.word, 1) +                 -- take first char from left
                 replicate('*', Len(t.word) - 2) + -- fill middle with *
                 right(t.word, 1)                  -- take last char from right
       end
from   @t t
```

this returns

| COLUMN1 |
| --- |
| b****a |
| s***l |
| v*******e |

If you want to keep 2 chars left and right when the len > 5 then maybe this

```
select case when len(t.word) < 3 then t.word
            when len(t.word) < 6 then 
                 left(t.word, 1) +
                 replicate('*', len(t.word) - 2) +
                 right(t.word, 1)
            else left(t.word, 2) +
                 replicate('*', len(t.word) - 4) +
                 right(t.word, 2)   
       end
from   @t t
```

The result

| COLUMN1 |
| --- |
| ba**na |
| s***l |
| ve*****le |

**EDIT:  What if there is a whole sentence ?**

Well then we first split the sentence in words,
and then concat the individual words back together while putting the ** in them

```
declare @t table (word varchar(50))
insert into @t values ('banana'), ('selin'), ('vegetable'), ('Banana is a fruit')

select t.word,
       -- put the words back togheter into the sentence, and ** them while we are at it
       ( select string_agg(case when len(value) < 3 then value
                                when len(value) < 6 then 
                                     left(value, 1) +
                                     replicate('*', len(value) - 2) +
                                     right(value, 1)
                                else left(value, 2) +
                                     replicate('*', len(value) - 4) +
                                     right(value, 2)   
                           end, 
                          ' ')
       )
from   @t t
  cross apply string_split(t.word, ' ') s -- split the sentence into words
group by t.word
```

the result is

```
word                COLUMN1
----                -------
banana              ba**na
Banana is a fruit   Ba**na is a f***t
selin               s***n
vegetable           ve*****le
```

Comment: What about a full sentence? Like "banana is a fruit" ba--na is a f---t?

Comment: @CJava I edited my answer to include a solution for full sentences

Comment: WARNING - both string_split and string_agg do NOT guarantee order.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on a few answers:

```
select case when len(@String) <= 3 then @String
            when len(@String) > 3 AND len(@String) <= 5 then
                 substring(@String, 1, 2) +
                 REPLICATE('*', Len(@String) - 2) +
                 substring(@String, Len(@String) - 1, 2)
            when len(@String) >= 6 then
                 substring(@String, 1, 2) +
                 REPLICATE('*', Len(@String) - 2) +
                 substring(@String, Len(@String) - 1, 2)    
            else 'unrecognized length!'
```

If the length of the string is less than or equal to 3, return the string.
If the length of the string is more than 3 and less than or equal to 5 then create a substring starting at position 1, then replicate * by the length of the string -2 and finally add another substring -1 from the end of the string.
Similar for if the result is over 6 characters.
Else unrecognized length!

Hope this helps understand what's going on!

Comment: Do you have a full working example on this? And what about "Banana is a fruit", ba--na is a f---t, full sentence?

Comment: Unrecognized length!  you're even accounting for negative lengths.

Comment: I agree with MarcinJ, you will never reach the else

Comment: Agreed! It was just an example as to what he could do with an else :)

Comment: @CJava if the first word was ALWAYS going to be a fruit/vegetable then you could extract just the first word, set that as your new string and do the same as above.

Edit just in case you needed to know how to do that:

SUBSTRING(@String,1,(CHARINDEX(' ',@String+ ' ')-1))